# pessimistic locking in GORM where query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, pessimistic-locking

I'd like to achieve pessimistic lock with GORM's where query.

Something like

```
def query = Person.where {
    firstName == "Bart"
}
//instead of where.findAll()
List personsLocked = where.lockAll()
```

I know, I can achieve that by criteria API:

```
List personsLocked = Person.createCriteria().list {
    eq('firstName', 'Bart')
    lock true
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this via the "where" query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock` is not available in the [grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/current/api/grails/gorm/DetachedCriteria.html) (result of `where`) and is only available from the [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/current/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/query/AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.html) provided by `createCriteira` or by explicitly calling `lock()` on the instances and thus changing the `LockMode` to `LockMode.UPGRADE`

You could always use the spread dot operator and lock the results after you get them.

Comment: By calling lock() on the returned instances, I would run into race condition (in the instant, when entity is read, but yet not locked). It seems that my only chance is to rewrite the query to criteria style.