# grails/hibernate - use lock with getAll() method

Tags: hibernate, grails, pessimistic-locking

As documented we could use obtain pessimistic lock like this:

```
def airport = Airport.get(10, [lock:true)
airport.lock() // lock for update
airport.name = "Heathrow"
airport.save()
```

I tried to de the same think with getAll but it doesn't work

```
def airport = Airport.getAll(idsList, [lock:true])
```

Error:

```
getAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, java.util.LinkedHashMap)...
```

Is there another way to obtain a pessimistic lock for a list?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `airports` is a collection of your domain instances you could use the spread dot operator like this: `airports*.lock()` Otherwise, no.

Comment: If I use `findAllByIdInList`, can I avoid the use of pessimistic lock?

Comment: See my previous answer regarding how to control pesimistic locks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808440/pessimistic-locking-in-gorm-where-query

Comment: Unrelated - you're using a weird locking approach - instead of `[lock:true]` or `lock()` after retrieving (or both, why 2?) just use the static lock method so there's no gap between retrieval and lock: `def airport = Airport.lock(10)`